# Loop over a list of objects and display it in lift

Tags: scala, lift

How do you look over an object and display the results, without having markup in your scala code?

I have the following code:

```
class User(id: Long, name: String)

class DisplayIt {
  def display = {
    val users = List(new User(0,"John"), new User(1, "James"))
    "#name *" #> users.map(_.name) &
    "#id *" #> users.map(_.id.toString)
  }
}


//In the html:
<div class="lift:DisplayIt.display">
  <div class="one-user">
    User <span id="name"> has the id <span id="id">
  </div>
</div>
```

What happens now is that I end with "User John James has the id 0 1", all within one div class="one-user".

How do I loop over it so I have one div class="one-user" for each user?

I know I can write the html/xml in scala code and do it that way, but is there a straightforward way to do it without any xml in the scala code?

Comment: Off topic comment, if you change your class User, fire a case class, you can avoid the   new   on your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
def display = {
  val users = List(new User(0, "John"), new User(1, "James"))
  ".one-user *" #> users.map { u =>
    "#name *" #> u.name &
    "#id *" #> u.id.toString
  }
}
```

Basically, you have to match a surrounding element first and apply a list of transformations to that.

Comment: I tried that, now it seems I get one-user repeated (which I wanted), but each one has the details of all users repeated in it. So I have two "User John James has the id 0 1"'s. Do I need to do something different with my html?

Comment: Update: Nevermind, it works perfectly. The problem was I wrapped my original code with the users.map and didn't change it to be u.name, I still had users.map(_.name)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def list = { ".one-user *" #> users.map( n => { 
  "#name *" #> n.name) & 
  "#id *" #> n.id.toString) 
  }
) }
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see Debilski's answer while I typed mine